# XAML - Stackpanel - seting starting offset

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

I am trying to arrange 3 full-screen sized elements (grids) with content in such way, that when the application starts one will be in the middle, one on every side and they would be uncyclable (TabNavigation="Once").

Here is what I have now:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="400"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                ZoomMode="Disabled"
                HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                TabNavigation="Once">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Background="Aqua" Width="400">
                <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0,0,30,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="339" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Hello World!</TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Green" Width="400">
                <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0,0,30,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="353" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Hello World!</TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="Crimson" Width="400">
                <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0,0,30,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="353" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Hello World!</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

What I want to achieve is to always open the app at the second element.

Any help is very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using `BringIntoView` method on second `Grid`?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you really need to be able to scroll in a continuous fashion? Can't you use a `ContentControl` and switch the `Content`, as for any standard navigation?

Answer (score 0):

a simple example for your case, I modified a bit

I am using an ItemsControl for hosting items and named the middle element

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <Grid Background="Aqua" Width="400">
            <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0,0,30,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="339" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Hello World!</TextBlock>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="middle" Background="Green" Width="400">
            <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0,0,30,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="353" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Hello World!</TextBlock>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="Crimson" Width="400">
            <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0,0,30,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="353" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Hello World!</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
```

then in your code behind

```
    Loaded += (s, e) => middle.BringIntoView();
```